# JQGrid Value and Text Column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a column that I want to display as a Text(e.g CityName) on read/display mode. When the user clicks edit, I want it to be displayed as a Select, i would then pass the CityID so that I can display the Select Control with options==CityID as selected.

Does jqGrid have this functionality out of the box or do I have to implement a custom formatter?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Got it already

Here is my solution

col Model

```
{ name: 'CityID', index: 'CityID', width: 55, editable: true, edittype: 'select',  editoptions: { dataUrl: 'City/GenerateCityOptions' }, formatter: CityFormatter},

function CityFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    return rowObject.CityName; //The field name that i wanted to be displayed instead of id

}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is during edit mode jqgrid selects the option by name and not by id. So if you have a duplicate item it would point to the same name but wrong id.